# Polymer - how to create element with binding

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I need to create polymer custom element with binding attribute.

```
<foo-bar baz="{{qux}}"></foo-bar>
```

It's OK.
But it must be created dynamically (tagName passed as an attribute). I try this

```
Polymer({
    ready: function() {
        var element = document.createElement(this.tagName);
        element.setAttribute('baz', '{{qux}}');
        this.$.placeholder.appendChild(element);
    }
});
```

But it does not work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `injectBoundHTML()`:

```
<div id="container"></div>

...

this.injectBoundHTML('<foo-bar baz="{{qux}}"></foo-bar>', this.$.container);
```

It's not documented yet, but more info is here: https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/607